# Fundamental group of Antoine's necklace

Tags: algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ denote [Antoine's necklace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine's_necklace). It is well-known that $A$ is a Cantor space and that $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash A$ is not simply connected. Futhermore, $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash A)$ is not even finitely-generated.

But what is really known this group? Is countable? Is it isomorphic to some classical group such that $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$? Is it torsion-free or abelian?

Comment: It is not one of the familiar groups: It contains abelian subgroups of rank 2, but also free subgroups; it is countable, as fundamental group of any manifold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In his book *Knots and Links*, Rolfsen shows that, writting Antoine's necklace $A$ as an intersection of chains of tori $\bigcap\limits_{n \geq 0} C_n$ as usual, the inclusions $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash C_n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \backslash C_{n+1}$ are $\pi_1$-injective, so that the fundamental group

$$ \pi_1( \mathbb{R}^3 \backslash A) = \bigcup\limits_{n \geq 0} \pi_1( \mathbb{R}^3 \backslash C_n)$$

is a limit of knot groups. In particular, we deduce that the group is countable, non-abelian and torsion-free (thanks to [studiosus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/684883/36434)).

Moreover, it is an exercice in Rolfsen's book to show that $H_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash A)=0$, so $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash A)$ is a perfect group (ie. equal to its own commutator subgroup).