# Subspaces of euclidean spaces with finite nontrivial homotopy groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Does there exist an $X\subseteq\Bbb R^3$ such that $\pi_1(X)$ is finite but nontrivial? (note that $X$ doesn't have to be a manifold or anything nice).

More generally let $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ be the function that maps $n$ to the smallest $m$ such that there is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$ whose $\pi_n$ is finite but nontrivial, is $f(n)=n+3$? If not what can be said about this function?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36279/is-the-fundamental-group-of-every-subset-of-mathbbr2-torsion-free

Comment: Thanks @MoisheCohen, I wish I had found that question before asking mine! I suppose there's not hope for the general case then and I should ask about which results are known for $\pi_1$ and $\Bbb R^3$ instead maybe

Comment: However as @PaulPlummer pointed out, it could be possible that it can be proved that there are no subspaces with finite nontrivial $\pi_1$, while the general question about torsion remains open

Comment: The standard algebraic topology invariants (like homotopy groups and singular co/homology groups) were designed for reasonably "nice" topological spaces (originally, smooth manifolds, later on - CW complexes). For more pathological spaces (such as arbitrary subsets of $R^n$) one should look for other invariants, for instance, Chech homotopy and cohomology groups, Sitnikov homology, etc.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sp perhaps the first step should be to ask whether there are finite polyhedra $P \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ having finite fundamental groups. Since the fundamental group of $P$ agrees with the fundamental group of the $2$-skeleton of $P$, it suffices to consider $2$-dimensional polyhedra $P \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Perhaps something is known about these spaces?

Comment: @PaulFrost: No, $\pi_1(P)$ will be torsion-free, see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680998/is-there-a-domain-in-mathbbr3-with-finite-non-trivial-pi-1-but-h-1-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have an answer to your first question (and I also do not find it very natural since you are considering arbitrary subsets of $R^3$, see my comment above). I will answer the second question.

No, $f(n)\ne n+3$. For instance, $f(4)=3$ since $\pi_4(S^2)\ne 0$ and every subset of $R^2$ has trivial higher homotopy groups. For the same reason, $f(n)=3$, $n\ge 4$. Indeed, $\pi_i(S^2)$ is finite for every $i\ge 4$, and is nonzero, see

S. Ivanov, R. Mikhailov, J. Wu, "[On nontriviality of homotopy groups of spheres](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00952)", 2015.

Read more on homotopy groups of spheres [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres).

"The difference between general topology and algebraic topology is that the former asks simple questions about complicated spaces while the latter asks difficult questions about simple spaces."

**Edit.** Just for completeness:

1. For every open connected subset $U\subset R^3$, $\pi_1(U)$ is torsion-free, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680998/is-there-a-domain-in-mathbbr3-with-finite-non-trivial-pi-1-but-h-1-0).
2. Consequently, for every compact connected subset $K\subset R^3$ its **Chech fundamental group** $\check{\pi}_1(K)$ is also torsion-free. This is because 
   $$
   \check{\pi}_1(K)\cong colim_{U} \pi_1(U)
   $$
   where the inverse limit is taken over all open neighborhoods of $K$ in $R^3$.
3. Therefore, for every connected CW complex $C$ (more generally, an ENR) which admits a (topological) embedding $C\to R^3$, $\pi_1(C)$  is torsion-free.

Comment: I accepted the answer since the first question seems very likely to be open, just a quick question, what does ENR mean?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: This means **Euclidean Neighborhood Retract**: There exists a neighborhood of $C$ in $R^3$ which retracts to $C$.