# How can I show the trefoil group is torsion-free

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-presentation, low-dimensional-topology

I would like to show the trefoil group is torsion-free. The trefoil group has the presentation
\begin{equation}
G = \langle a, b \mid a^3 = b^2\rangle.
\end{equation}
I tried to map this to a simpler torsion-free group, for instance, if $h: G\to \mathbb{Z}$ by
\begin{equation}
a\to 2, b\to 3,
\end{equation}
then the torsion of $G$ must be in the kernel of $h$. However, the kernel is still pretty complicated.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In general, an open subset of $R^3$ has no torsion in the fundamental group, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680998/is-there-a-domain-in-mathbbr3-with-finite-non-trivial-pi-1-but-h-1-0). Perhaps there is a more direct approach though.

Comment: You could talk about the group elements in terms of words consisting of 'a's and 'b's and their inverses, and talk about their length after resolving a letter with its inverse, and frame the relation $aaa \to bb$ as a "rewrite rule" for those words, and prove that with that one rewrite rule there is now way to get a word of length one. ... This would all have to be made rigorous though, but I think approaching the task with that mindset helps.

Comment: @MikePierce I think you mean there no way to reduce a word to length _zero_.

Comment: One way to see torsion-free-ness is to realise that this is a free product with amalgamation of two torsion-free groups (namely two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$). The result from here is pretty standard (e.g. via Bass-Serre theory, or I think in Magnus, Karrass and Solitar's book *Combinatorial Group Theory*). Alternatively, the group is a one-relator group whose relator is not a proper power, and so is torsion-free (this is definitely proven in Magnus, Karrass and Solitar, although better proofs exist now).

Comment: The trefoil group is isomorphic to $ B_3 $, the braid group on 3 strands. And all braid groups are known to be torsion-free. Not self contained but maybe convincing for someone who thinks about braid groups a lot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to rewrite  user1729's comment in more detail.

The theorem used is the following and can be found for example in Serre's Trees (Thm 8)

> Every finite subgroup of $G=G_1\ast_A G_2$ is contained in a conjugate of $G_1$ or $G_2$.

Now, the trefoil group can be writen in the form $G=\mathbb{Z}\ast_A \mathbb{Z}$ where $A=\mathbb{Z}=\langle a \rangle$ and the two homomorphisms $f_2:A\to \mathbb{Z}=\langle x \rangle,\ f_3:A\to \mathbb{Z}=\langle y \rangle$ are $f_2(a)=x^2,\ f_3(a)=y^3$.

Therefore, if $g\in G$ is a torsion element then it should be an element of one of the two $\mathbb{Z}$'s. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ has no torsion elements it has to be $g=1$.

Comment: +1 Nice profile picture! (Also, it is maybe worth pointing out that the proof of Serre's Theorem 8 is not difficult, and is a nice introductory proof on groups acting on trees.)